# Usage of bandwidth when uploading from a form

Tags: php, ftp

I need to know how much bandwidth is used when uploading a file through a form.

Let me explain a bit more easily.  I have a file containing a upload form that is hosted on a web host.  When the user uploads a file it is uploaded through this form and to another server through FTP, so basically I'm creating a FTP connection inside the PHP file that is stored on a web host.

How much bandwidth is used if I upload a 100MB file?  And is it the receiving server (the server we upload to through FTP in PHP file), is it the web host (where we are hosting the PHP file that opens the FTP connection) or is it both that uses the bandwidth needed to upload a 100MB file?

Comment: you'll use 200 meg + overhead. 100meg user->your server, and 100meg your server->ftp server. they'll be two completely distinct TCP connections, and whatever is metering your bandwidth will count the bytes separately.

Comment: The file upload through a form will take 133MB. The FTP transfer just 100MB, but that's seldomly quota'ed (consult your hoster).

Comment: @mario That would depend entirely on the encoding used for the form.

Comment: @mario: Where did 133MB come from?

Comment: So even if the file never uploads to the web host,  it will use the double amount of bandwith it would use if I uploaded it to the web host?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's pretty much always base64-encoded in a multipart transfer (so 1/3 overhead).

Comment: Kind of like cellphone charges when you're out of your country. Double the bill, *ouch*. Double dinger ringer charges.

Comment: You should also check to see if the file first exists, without having to go through all of that for nothing. That's if you're checking for duplicates or not. You'll need some form of renaming function to avoid duplicates.

Comment: It is using multipart for upload and FTP_BINARY when transferring the file to the other server, my script checks if the file input is empty and it also is giving files "random" names to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use 100MB of bandwidth (transfer to first server) and another 100MB of bandwidth (transfer to another server), that's 200MB of bandwidth.  100MB download, 100MB upload.  Sometimes your provider will bill those separately.

100 + 100 = 200.  It really is that simple.

(Note that there is overhead in all cases, but not a ton.)

Comment: So for it to be successful I should have 2 servers with unlimited bandwidth usage? 1 For handeling the data to the first server and 1 for handeling the 2nd transfer which is through the FTP protocol

Comment: @ZakariyaHarrak I have no idea what you're asking really.  You need to pay for the bandwidth you use... that doesn't mean you need "unlimited" bandwidth (which isn't really a thing anyway).

Comment: well unmetered in that matter that I would never reach the limit. But you guys have answered my question.